# are signed integer and unsigned integer one-one mapping with each other?

Tags: c, encoding, unsigned, unsigned-long-long-int

I want to make ip-port pair as a search key, so I have the following function

```
    int64_t make_pair(u_int32_t ip, u_int16_t port)
    {
            u_int64_t ip_u64 = ip;
            ip_u64 = ip_u64 << 16;
            int64_t ip_port_pair = (int64_t)(ip_u64 + (u_int64_t)port);
            return ip_port_pair;
    }
```

indeed, I want to transform a u_int64_t to int64_t because it is not convenient for unsigned integer to compare value. But I'm afraid the cast from u_int64_t to int64_t is not one-one mapping and then there are some conflicts or search error.

so I want to ask is the cast from u_int64_t to int64_t is not one-one mapping or not? thanks!

Comment: It is on all the machines I know about.

Comment: What's inconvenient about comparing unsigned integers?

Comment: The 1990s called. They want their IPv4-specific assumptions back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard guarantees that `int64_t` uses two's-complement representation with no padding bits, so it's implicitly guaranteed that there's a one-to-one mapping. (<strike>I believe it's still possible for the most negative value to be a trap representation, but that's unlikely in practice.</strike> Unlike ordinary signed integer types, the `intN_t` types cannot make the most negative value a trap representation; all 2<sup>N</sup> possible representations are well-defined and have distinct values.)

On the other hand, there's no guarantee that `int64_t` exists.

A conversion from `uint64_t` to `int64_t` yields an implementation-defined result for values outside the range of `int64_t`. The result is almost certain to be the one you'd probably expect, produced by simply reinterpreting the representation, but it's not guaranteed.

So in practice, you can very probably get away with converting between `int64_t` and `uint64_t`.

But why do you need to? You say it's "because it is not convenient for unsigned integer to compare value". What's inconvenient about it? The relational operators are well defined for both signed and unsigned types.

Comment: Your "almost" is overly cautious. C requires INTN_MIN to have the value -2^(N-1). See 7.18.2.1 Limits of exact-width integer types. Your second paragraph is correct, however. The *safe* way to convert from `uintNN_t` to `intNN_t` is with `memcpy` or a union. The other direction is always safe and well-defined.